# Run a soft in debug mode on a computer which haven't visual 2008

Tags: c++, qt, odbc, driver

I would like to run my Qt application on a computer which haven't visual 2008 installed.
It seems I can't manage to use QODBC driver in debug mode on this computer.
All is ok in release.

Any ideas ?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of error message do you get?
Did you try GDB ?

Comment: "Driver Not Loaded" return by QSqlDatabase::isValid()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you dropped the VS2008 debug runtime where your qodbc driver ist installed?
VS2008 has it's debug runtime here by default

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86

Comment: As the name suggests, this runtime is non-redistributable. It's OK to copy this to a test computer in your company, but you can't ship this to customers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried it, but the problem persist.

Comment: @MSalters: yes I'm only restrain this to a test computer.

Comment: The only solution I have found it's to install VS2008 on the test computer..but i am not very happy about this solution.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest tool to solve "it doesn't load" problems on Windows is [Dependency Walker aka Depends](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). Used in profiling mode, it will trace which DLLs the program loads, and in case of a failure it will show you where a DLL failed to load. This is especially useful when a program does load on one machine, since you can then compare the two logs.

Comment: All seems ok with dependency walker. At least two dlls (IESHIMS.dll and WER.dll) are not found but same thing happen when I launch dependecy on a computer on which VS2008 is installed (and so on which my application correctly start).